# Workflow codeactivity to download file from document library

Tags: 2013, visual-studio-2012, workflow-activity

The following code works in a console application but returns a 401 error from a workflow code activity. The aim is to download and process a .eml file from a Sharepoint 2013 document library. SP and WF both reside on the same server.

> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. 
>   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() 
>   at ActivityLibrary2.CodeActivity1.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(Url);
request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
request.PreAuthenticate = true;
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
WebResponse response = (WebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

I've also tried DefaultNetworkCredentials, specifying credentials, same result. The workflow app pool account has full access to the site.

Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a WCF service for this code using DefaultNetworkCredentials.

I had to grant "NT AUTHORITY\network service" access to the document library.